# Blobstore upload with AsiHttpRequest

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, asihttprequest, blobstore

I'm trying to store a blob with AsiHttpRequest in iOS and something doesn't work well.
when I'm asking the blobstoreserivce to produce an upload link it does the job.
when I'm trying to post to this link it gets back with a 411 error of 
"POST requests require a Content-length header"

**thats my iOS code**

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5)];

self.formData = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uri]];  
[self.formData setData:imageData withFileName:@"gal.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpg"    forKey:@"myFile"];
[self.formData setDelegate:self];
[self.formData setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
[self.formData setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[self.formData startAsynchronous];
```

ill be glad for some help
Gal

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Content-Length header to your request as follows:

```
[self.formData addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [imageData length]]];
```